# How to get existing index object, if index exists in php elastica

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elastica

I am new to elastic search. I am using php elastica client and facing a problem:
If an index exists, I want to get the object of this existing index and not recreate it. How can this be done?

```
client = new \Elastica\Client($arrServerConf, $callback);

if ( $client->getIndex($name)->exists() ) {
      //do something here to get this existing object -- what to do here???
} else {
      // create a new one
      $index = $client->getIndex($name);
      $index->create(array('index' => array('number_of_shards' => $shards, 'number_of_replicas' => 0)), $delete);
}
$type = $index->getType($typeName);
```

Or is there some other way of doing this?
I need this because, I'll be adding documents in this index and searching among them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. I could easily do it with the same:
$index = $client->getIndex($name);

There was some problem in my code itself.